# How to insert multiple images like shown in the attached image in my document?

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

Also, I am writing a paper in a two-column format. This whole thing is inside one column.[image]

Comment: Did you have a look to [`subfigure`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) package ?

Comment: No, I am totally new to TeX. This is going to be my first properly written paper with LaTeX. So I don't have much idea about the advance settings of figures.

Comment: @jchd `subfigure` is considered obsolete. It is superseded by `subfig` (originally by the same author) or `subcaption`.

Comment: You also have the  `subfigure` environment from `subcaption`  and `(sub)floatrow` from the `floatrow` package.

Comment: @campa oh really? Didn't know, thanks! I wish I was warned about this during compilation, but that did not happen. Is my TeXLive distribution deprecated? :p
My answer needs an edit BTW.

Comment: @jchd There is no warning because it's perfectly fine to use it! It's anyway part of any TeXLive distribution (backward compatibility). But since it is not maintained any more it should better not be used for new documents.

Comment: @campa, right, I changed the answer, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`subfig`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) documentation for full details, but a MWE would work like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[IMG1]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{img1.jpeg}} \quad %use \qquad for larger spacing
\subfloat[IMG2]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{img2.jpeg}}
\caption{Two images on the same figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to [@campa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/82917/campa) for pointing out that the `subfigure` package is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. This is working. I didn't know about this package before.